# Django media files get 403 forbidden

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn, django-media

I have an app running on a Digital Ocean Droplet. I'm using Ubuntu, Nginx and Gunicorn

The admin can upload media files, the upload is working fine.
The problem is that when a user visits the site, the media files that the admin uploaded are not displayed due to a 403 (forbidden) error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the link had expired. I had used Digital Ocean spaces which in turn uses AWS S3 bucket for media storage. I saved an image url that had been generated in my db and when I tried to use it later, it didn't work. It turned out that the link had an expiry time set to it and had expired hence the `403 forbidden` error I was getting

`https://fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/.../...png?AWSAccessKeyId=...&Signature=...&Expires=1702289262`